# How to define a BaseConfigration for all other configuration in EF7 code first?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to define a `base configuration` (for some reason) for all model configuration(which using fluent api on them), so i create `BaseConfigration` class:

```
 public class BaseConfigration<T> : EntityTypeBuilder<T> where T : class
   {
       public BaseConfigration(InternalEntityTypeBuilder builder) :base(builder)
       {
       }
    }
```

and all of other configuration inherit from it:

```
 public class LoyaltyActivityConfig : BaseConfigration<LoyaltyActivity>
  {
    public LoyaltyActivityConfig(InternalEntityTypeBuilder builder) : base(builder)
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Title).HasMaxLength(100);
    }

 }
```

in this point all thing goes right, but when i want to introduce this configuration in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
 new LoyaltyActivityConfig(modelBuilder.Entity<NotificationPlatform>());
```

it gives me error:

> cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder'

How can i do it?

Comment: [This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder__ctor_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Internal_InternalEntityTypeBuilder_)

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message says, you are using incorrect type. During `OnModelCreating` you have `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` object. `InternalEntityTypeBuilder` should not be used in user code as its internal to EF core as said in documentation.

To define a `BaseConfiguration` which will be applied to each entity type in the model and derived by `EntityTypeConfiguration`, code should be organized in following manner:

```
public class BaseConfiguration<T> where T : class 
{
    public BaseConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<T> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        // Write fluent API code here which will be applied to all entityTypes in the model
        entityTypeBuilder.HasKey("Id");
    }
}

public class LoyaltyActivityConfig : BaseConfiguration<LoyaltyActivity>
{
    public LoyaltyActivityConfig(EntityTypeBuilder<LoyaltyActivity> entityTypeBuilder)
        : base(entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        // Write fluent API code here which will be applied to EntityType LoyaltyActivity only
        entityTypeBuilder.Property(x => x.Title).HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

Then call above code from `OnModelCreating` like this

```
new LoyaltyActivityConfig(modelBuilder.Entity<LoyaltyActivity>());
```

Above method will call `BaseConfiguration` constructor followed by `EntityTypeConfiguration` constructor, applying all fluent API code.

Few things to remember here,

In `BaseConfiguration` even if you have generic `EntityTypeBuilder` you will not be able to use generic methods since `T` is unknown type. You can define an interface which will be implemented by every T (all entity types in the model) and use generic methods afterwards. Using non-generic methods will also get you same result though. Its just matter of readability.

You can also use method calls instead of constructor in Config classes to achieve the same.

To organize code like above, `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` feature from EF6 has been implemented in EF core and will be available in 2.0 release. More info https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2805